# Нужна помощь с .join

Tags: python, python-3.x

Возникает ошибка в коде, помогите понять в чем дело.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kali/Рабочий стол/main.py", line 40, in <module>
    s = ' '.join(collisions[i])
KeyError: 0
```

Код:

```
from bitarray import bitarray
from bitarray.util import ba2int    # pip install bitarray


def CRC(arg):
    arg = format(arg, 'b') # Представляем входное сообщение битовой строкой
    arg+= "00000" # Добавляем входному сообщению пять нулей, что соотв, домножению на x*5
    bits = bitarray(arg) # Представляем как массив бит

    for i in range(len(bits) - 5):
        if bits[i] == 1:
            bits[i] ^= 1 # Когда встречаем единицу в старшем разряде -
            bits[i+3] ^= 1 # выполняем побитовый XOR в соответствии с G(x) = x°5 + x°2 + 1
            bits[i+5] ^= 1

    return ba2int(bits) # Возвращаем полученное значение функции целым числом

while True:
    opt = int(input('''\n1) Получение значения хеш-фушкции CRC для входного сообщения (1 байт)
                       \n2) Поиск всех коллизий хеш-функции для всех аргументов (1 байт)
                       \n0) Выход
                       \nВыберите одну из предложенных опций: '''))
    if opt == 0:
        break
    elif opt == 1:
        arg = int(input("\nВведите целое число от 0 до 255: "))
        f = CRC(arg)
        print(f"\nВычисленное значение: {format(f, 'b')}")
    elif opt == 2:
        collisions = {} # Создаем словарь ключ - значение CRC функции, значение словаря - список аргументов
# при которых CRC функция принимает данное значение CRC

        for i in range(256):
            f = CRC(1)
            if f in collisions:
                collisions[f].append(str(i)) # Если такой ключ уже есть - добавляем в список аргумент
            else:
                collisions[f] = [str(i)] # Если нет - создаем список с аргументом
        print("Значение хеш-функции\tАргументы при которых получается данное значение")
        for i in range(32): # Т.к. x*5 - перебираем уже вычисленные значения функции от до 31
            s = ' '.join(collisions[i])
            print(f"\t{format(i, 'b')}\t\t{s}") # формируем строки и выводим
        else:
            print("\nОшибка ввода попробуйте еще раз: ")
```

Comment: помогаю: проблема совсем не с .join, а в том, что в словаре collisions нет ключа 0. Чтение и понимание ошибок - 80% на пути их решения.

Comment: @Эникейщик Не совсем понимаю... Как в данном случае исправить

Comment: ну как исправить... если вы пытаетесь достать из кармана 10 рублей, а там нет 10 рублей, то надо или не пытаться достать оттуда 10 рублей, или сначала положить туда 10 рублей, а потом уже доставать.

Answer (score 1):

```
        for i in range(256):
            f = CRC(1) # ОШИБКА! Аргумент функции - константа
```

Так вы не используете переменную цикла `i` и вычисляете `CRC` всегда от аргумента `1`. Исправьте это и всё заработает как нужно:

```
        for i in range(256):
            f = CRC(i) # теперь правильно
```

Comment: Большое спасибо.